# Android studio - How to see again the phone in the small right preview window

Tags: android

I made the tutorial Android (https://developer.android.com/training/index.html); i saw the phone in the small preview window and it was ok; but the phone disappear (the preview window is still there) and is replaced by a big very tall and too much slow window that i don't want.

How to find again my phone in the small right preview window ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Refresh" icon in the preview window